# Freebsd 10.2 Virtualbox 4.3.40: Has anyone managed to install Windows 10 guest on Freebsd 10.2 host?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, freebsd

I am having problems installing Windows 10 as a guest in VirtualBox 4.3.30 running on a FreeBSD 10.2 host. Has anyone managed to install it? The blue Windows 10 splash screen appears but then the install hangs, VirtualBox spins at 100% CPU load and nothing else happens.

Comment: Windows 10 only works (relatively) properly in the very latest 5.x versions.

Comment: I actually recompiled 5.0 from Svn on Freebsd. However the behaviour is the same. Maybe the Freebsd kernel driver is not updated or something else that is Freebsd dependent is different to Linux or other platforms. At least the install dialog appears when running on Linux in Virtualbox 4.3.30 ... I guess I have to stay on Windows 7 for Bsd.

Comment: I switched from a Lenovo t430s (Intel) to a AMD desktop. There the VirtualBox 5.0 recompile can boot Window-10. The difference seem to be in VT-x versus AMD-v or maybe I configured the bios wrongly on the t430s. I enabled VT-x there I think.